# where can I see my custom post type archive template?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, archives

I am working with wordpress 3.1 and have custom post type of whitepaper. My single-whitepaper template seems to be working. But the archive template (archive-whitepaper.php) is not.

And this after I have added the new 'has_archive' parameter to my register post type function. I have tried setting it to true and I have tried setting it to a slug of 'whitepaper'

But when I hit the url example.com/whitepaper, I get a white screen. Here's my code:

```
register_post_type( 'whitepaper', array(
               'labels' => array(
               'name' => __( 'Whitepapers' ),
               'singular_name' => __( 'Whitepaper' ),
               'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
               'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Whitepaper' ),
               'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
               'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Whitepaper' ),
               'new_item' => __( 'New Whitepaper' ),
               'view' => __( 'View Whitepaper' ),
               'view_item' => __( 'View Whitepaper' ),
               'search_items' => __( 'Search Whitepapers' ),
               'not_found' => __( 'No whitepapers found' ),
               'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No whitepapers found in Trash' ),
               'description' => __( 'Whitepaper type is used to post recommended viewing content for our users.' )                  
                  ),
                  'public' => true,
                  'show_ui' => true,
                  'publicly_queryable' => true,
                  'exclude_from_search' => false,
          'menu_position' => 5,
          'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/whitepaper.png',
          'query_var' => true,
          'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
          'can_export' => true,
          'has_archive' => 'whitepaper'
 )
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Save permalinks to flush your rewrite rules:

[image: Saving Permalinks in WordPress to Flush rewrite rules]

Comment: Thanks mike for the tip but there was a syntax error in my template. Issue solved

Comment: @Amit Erandole - What was the syntax error?  I copied your code into my test site and it worked fine.

Comment: @Mike - Just visiting the permalinks page should be enough.

Comment: @t31os - Visiting the permalinks page should be enough for what? To see the error?  I didn't see any errors on my test site.

Comment: @Mike - To update the rewrite rules silly ;-)

Comment: @t31os - I'm still confused, but it's unimportant.

Comment: No need to click Save on the permalinks page. :)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel When you create a new custom post type, sometime the archive page shows 404 not found error. To overcome, we must flush the rewrite rules and that can be done by re-saving your link structure.