# Custom post type permalinks breaking due to 3.1 bug fix

Tags: posts, permalinks, customization

So I just updated a site to 3.1 that uses several custom post types.

When I had made the site I had not noticed at the time the `$post_type` parameter for `register_post_type` has to be in all lowercase letters! ( it was not well written in the codex but now it is **bold**).
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters

My custom post types were registered with a capitol letter for instance "Rentals" instead of 'rentals'. This was fixed in 3.1 thus any posts registered with upper case letters were totally broken in the back and front end.

I was able to go back into the function and change it to lowercase and then call another function to update the database with the new name before it fires thanks to a post on wordpress.org by dennis_f.

Here new function

```
if(!get_option('custom_type_updated')){
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_type = 'custom-rental' WHERE post_type = 'Custom-Rental'");
update_option('custom_type_updated','true');
}
```

and here is the register re-written in lowercase

```
// Custom page template for rentals      -----------------
function Rental_register_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'custom-rental', array(
        'public'        => true,
        'can_export'    => true,
        'has_archive'   => 'Rentals',
        'rewrite'       => true,
        'supports' => array(
                ** bunch of supports stuff
            ),
        'labels' => array(
            **bunch of labels
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'Rental_register_post_type', 0 );
```

This did fix the major issue of broken custom post types BUT
the problem is now using a custom permalink structure breaks the custom post type 'rentals', only the default works.

For example www.example.com/?custom-rental=7-bedrooms works fine, but no custom permalink structure works, I have tried each type and cleared the .htaccess and just returns a 404.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show example URLs that don't work?  Did you [flush your permalinks](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10885/where-can-i-see-my-custom-post-type-archive-template/10887#10887)? Also I note your value fro `'has_archive'` is still not lowercase?

Comment: Wow Mike I did flush the permalinks. But after reading your comment I though wth I'll click it 2x, second click flushed it and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this from happening simply add `flush_rewrite_rules( false );` after your register_post_type function.
you can read about it more here 
http://en.bainternet.info/2011/custom-post-type-getting-404-on-permalinks